# Range within an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I came up with an algorithm and I wanted to ask something. Is there any way to set a range of values within an array?

Eg

```
int N = 10;
int array[N] = {2,6,5,9,4,3,5,9,4,9};
```

and using a loop to increase the start value with each pass.

```
for (int A = 1; A < N - 2; A++) {
    for (int B = 1; B < N - 1; B++) {
        int ProfitA = Sum(array[0...A-1]);
        int ProfitB = Sum(array[A...A+B-1]);
        int ProfitC = Sum(array[A+B...N-1]);
    }
}
```

So is there any way to set the range of  values in each array using the above C -pseudocode?

Comment: No, you'd have to write your own summing function and provide it with the array and the indices range.

Comment: As @lared said, You will have to replace each Sum in your pseudo-code with a for loop

Comment: you mean waht exactly? Is there any other way? Please explain.

Comment: the complexity of the prgramm is O(n^2) not O(n^3) . What I suppose to do to make the above code more efficient?

Comment: You could write a function which takes the array and indices as parameters, something like (assuming the array stores ints) - `int Sum(int *array, int start, int end);`

Comment: @lared you mean for the sum function right?

Comment: Yes, i do mean the sum function. As to efficiency the above program is O(n^3) due to the naive usage of `Sum` - it has to traverse the array to get the sums after all. You should consider caching the sums (for example ProfitA changes only by array[A-1] with each iteration of the outer loop, but you perform (N-2)*(A-1)  operations per iteration of the outer loop (N-2 iterations of the inner loop + A-1 iterations to calculate the sum per iteration) instead of just a single one!

Comment: Hmmmmm this is frustrating. So the best complexity is O(n^3)?

Comment: You can reduce it to O(n^2) by use of caching the sums and modifying them accordingly. Notice that ProfitA doesn't depend on the value of B, but you still included it in the inner loop. Similarly with each change of B ProfitB and ProfitC only vary by the value of ONE element of the array. Try to write the sums in the consecutive iterations down to see the pattern. There might be an even faster solution but I don't know what the code is meant to do.

Comment: @lared I created a code but isn't working and I can't understand why. Can I uploaded here to see it. I not I want to chat again with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C does not have such functionality built in. Moreover, there is no functionality to get the upper boundary of an array once you pass it to a function (so called "decaying to pointers").

There are two standard solutions to this problem:

- Pass a pointer to the first array element and the count of elements, or
- Pass a pointer to the whole array, an index to the initial element, and an index to the last element

The first approach would look like this:

```
int sum_array(int* array, size_t len) {
    int res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i != len ; i++) {
        res += array[i];
    }
    return res;
}
...
int ProfitA = sum_array(array, A);
int ProfitB = sum_array(array+A, B);
int ProfitC = sum_array(array+A+B, N-A-B);
```

the second approach would look like this:

```
int sum_array(int* array, int first, int last) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = first ; i <= last ; i++) {
        res += array[i];
    }
    return res;
}
...
int ProfitA = sum_array(array, 0, A-1);
int ProfitB = sum_array(array, A, A+B-1);
int ProfitC = sum_array(array, A+B, N-1);
```

Comment: so I need also a function sum_array. And more nested for loops.

Comment: @NikosKLon I don't know what you mean by "more nested loops", but the function `sum_array` does the trick. You can rewrite the algorithm in a way to avoid looping when computing sums, but that would be a different algorithm.

Comment: @dasbblinklight can you set me the idea of the "another algorithm"?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way using the style of syntax you used to describe what you're after.

Two obvious ways would be to provide the array and indices range (as lared mentioned) or specify the range using two pointers

```
int ProfitB = Sum(array + A, array + A+B-1);   /* sum array[A] ... array[A+B-1] */
```

Whichever approach you use, your calling code would need to ensure it provides a valid range.